# Solve $(x+1)^2= \frac{2bc+2xbc-ab}{ac}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to solve the following equation for $x$? That is, to rearrange the other variables such that I get a formula for $x$? Is there some other way to solve for $x$? I've ended up with this as a result of a maximization problem in calculus (I'm self-taught), but my algebra skills are not up to the task.

$$(x+1)^2= \frac{2bc+2xbc-ab}{ac}$$

Comment: Where is the square root?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a quadratic equation for $x$.  Expand the square on the left, move all the terms from the right to the left, segregate the term from the right that has a factor $x$ and you should be able to find $A,B,C$ where you have $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$  (Hint:  $A=1$)

Answer (score 1):

$(x+1)^2=\large\frac{2bc(x+1)-ab}{ac}$

Substitute $x+1=y$

$(ac)y^2-(2bc)y+ab=0$

This is a quadratic in $y$

Solve using $\large y=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Edit:In this example, $a$(coeff of $y^2$) is $ac$, $b$(coeff of $y$) is $-2bc$ and $c$(constant) is $ab$

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a quadratic equation, the objective is to get manipulate the equation so that it is in $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ form. \begin{align}
(x+1)^2&= \frac{2bc+2xbc-ab}{ac} \\
x^2+2x+1&= \frac{2bc}{ac}+\frac{2xbc}{ac}-\frac{ab}{ac} \\
x^2+2x+1&= \frac{2b}{a}+\frac{2b}{a}x-\frac{b}{c} \\
x^2+2x-\frac{2b}{a}x+1-\frac{2b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}&= 0 \\
\underbrace{(1)}_Ax^2+\underbrace{\left(2-\frac{2b}{a} \right)}_Bx+\underbrace{\left(1-\frac{2b}{a}+\frac{b}{c} \right)}_C &=0
\end{align}
Now apply the quadratic forula.
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A} \\
&=\frac{-\left(2-\frac{2b}{a} \right)\pm\sqrt{\left(2-\frac{2b}{a} \right)^2-4(1)\left(1-\frac{2b}{a}+\frac{b}{c} \right)}}{2(1)} 
\end{align}
Can you simplify this from here?

Comment: @Dmoreno I did not understand how the edit improved this post substantially.

Comment: Hi @Glacier. It really grinds my gears those $4(1)$, $2(1)$, etc. I think that using $\times$ make things more clear.